# react native TextInput onBlur get unedfined at android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My react-native version is 0.38.0

```
<TextInput onBlur={ (event) =>
   this.handleBlurCheck(event.nativeEvent.text,params) } />
```

In function `handleBlurCheck`, I get the value at iOS, but I get `undefined` at Android.

How to get value when `TextInput` is blurred on android platform?

The `nativeEvent` object on iOS:

```
nativeEvent:{
    eventCount: 5,
    target: 1046,
    text: '56'
}
```

The `nativeEvent` on Android:

```
nativeEvent:{
    target: 1046,
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with **onEndEditing**, like

```
<TextInput onEndEditing={ (event) => this.handleBlurCheck(event.nativeEvent.text,params) } />
```

You may look into the reported issue [here](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2555)

Answer (score 0):

I just use onChange to get the value.

```
  onChange={(event) => this.setState({
                         value: event.nativeEvent.text
                       })}
```

and trigger the functions on blur

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on the arguments is really limited:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.38/docs/textinput.html

Though as a walk around one can use

```html
<TextInput
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
  onEndEditing={() => this.handleBlurCheck(this.state.text, params)}
/>
```

---

**UPD.**

Another working solution to consider would be:

```
<TextInput
  onEndEditing={(e) => this.handleBlurCheck(e.nativeEvent.text, params)}
/>
```

**Detailed description:**

Looking at the source code it is obvious that what you get is exactly what is sent:
[ReactTextInputBlurEvent.java](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.38-stable/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/textinput/ReactTextInputBlurEvent.java#L43-L47)

```
private WritableMap serializeEventData() {
  WritableMap eventData = Arguments.createMap();
  eventData.putInt("target", getViewTag());
  return eventData;
}
```

Unlike iOS code that has everything in place:
[RCTEventDispatcher.m](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/c47759a9ae757ddaabde560a6b2af92e70a92453/React/Base/RCTEventDispatcher.m#L98-L137)

```
NSMutableDictionary *body = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:@{
  @"eventCount": @(eventCount),
  @"target": reactTag
}];

if (text) {
  body[@"text"] = text;
}

if (key) {
  if (key.length == 0) {
    key = @"Backspace"; // backspace
} else {
  switch ([key characterAtIndex:0]) {
    case '\t':
    key = @"Tab";
    break;
    case '\n':
    key = @"Enter";
    default:
    break;
  }
}
body[@"key"] = key;
```

However if we look at the "onEndEditing" event:
[ReactTextInputEndEditingEvent.java](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.38-stable/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/textinput/ReactTextInputEndEditingEvent.java#L49-L54)

```
private WritableMap serializeEventData() {
  WritableMap eventData = Arguments.createMap();
  eventData.putInt("target", getViewTag());
  eventData.putString("text", mText);
  return eventData;
}
```

the `text` property is set there.

Answer (score 0):

on blur function has these kind of parameters.

`onBlur = (event, newValue, previousValue) =>{ }`

in ios changed value is given by

> newValue

parameter but in android it is given by

> previousValue

so you can use this logic for get the text value.

```
import {isUndefined} from 'lodash';

onBlur = (event, nv, pv) =>{ 
  const value = isUndefined(nv)? pv:nv;
  // use value to as the text field value
}
```