# Call onBlur on tap of outside the textInput component

Tags: react-native, onblur, react-native-textinput

```
render(){
   return(
      <View style={{ flex:1 }}>
         <TextInput style={{ backgroundColor:'red'}} onFocus={() => alert('Focued')}
            onBlur={() => alert('Blurred') } 
         />
      </View>
   )
}
```

In the above code snippet when I click on textinput the focus operation is working, but when I click outside the textinput component onBlur is not triggered.

I don't want to enclose the component in scrollview

could any one help me out on this.

Comment: This link might solve your bug https://stackoverflow.com/a/47347235/12779513

Comment: @Yagaizhan , my scenario is I will click on textinput and then I won't type anything and just tap outside the textinput . In this scenario I am not able to fire onBlur

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I also am trying.

Comment: @Noitidart yes i was able to solve the issue..

Comment: @Shariq can you please share solution, I'm still struggling.

Comment: @Noitidart can you please share the code snippet.

Comment: @Shariq I don't have any working solution on how to detect tap outside of <TextInput> :(